# Cannot install anything PLEASE HELP

Tags: software-installation, updates, downloads, error-handling

Okay, so I know nothing about the terminal or any of that. I'm new to this "Ubuntu" stuff. My computer was fine and I could install and download programs but my computer broke, and once fixed, now I can't download or install anything. When I try downloading from the software center, it gives me a message saying "couldn't fetch" or using old ones or something.( can't add what it says because I don't have 10 rep)
if I try to use terminal, it says:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: reading files list for package 'brasero-common': Input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

PLEASE can anyone help me???? I've searched all over the internet with no luck. I’m using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I’ve been dealing with this problem FOR MONTHS! with no solution. Please help :( (cant even install updates , it says failed to download all packages)

Comment: Please read this: https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask. Concentrate on one topic at a time and be precise.

Comment: im just trying to get help with why my computer wont download or install any programs. that is my topic. im new to ubuntu and its  so difficult to understand.